# Converting string to onclick handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable `ElementAction` which is a string `javascript:deleteRow();`. How do I assign the literal content of `ElementAction` to an `onclick` handler of another HTML element. `HTMLElement.onclick = ElementAction` doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can using `eval`, however **I absolutely don't recommend** running a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of that "javascript:" prefix first; it's useless. You can create a function instance from your string with:

```
var handler = new Function("event", ElementAction.replace(/^javascript:/, ''));
```

Then you can attach the handler either by setting the "onclick" attribute directly or by using one of the APIs as in JCOC611's answer.

Comment: By the way I just realized that the "javascript:" prefix does work because it ends up acting as a **label** on the first statement of the function body :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
element.onclick = deleteRow;
```

Or even more compatible:

```
if(element.attachEvent){
   element.attachEvent("onclick", deleteRow);
}else{
   element.addEventListener("click", deleteRow, false);
}
```

Running a string is **not recommended**.